# Started with incorrect URL format - how to change?

Tags: wordpress, url, subdomain

I originally set up my Wordpress blog using the URL format = http: / /www. example. com/subdomain - I had no experience of doing this and assumed that it wouldn't make any difference if I used
the www version or subdomain.example.com.

Now I've found a problem with AJAX loads that requires that pages have the subdomain.example.com format.

I want to find the best way to change the url format on the existing pages, I can see two ways of approaching this:

- Edit all the permalinks, about 25, and change everything to the subdomain.example.com format.
- Use a redirect in .htaccess, something I have no experience of.

The site is still in development so I don't have to worry changing the url from the point of view of historic visitors.

Question: Can anyone with experience in this area offer advice on the best approach to making this change - pitfalls, problems, pros, cons???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still in the development phase, you are probably better off from a performance standpoint editing the links to get the right format.  Adding another layer of rewrites is slower and has SEO ramifications.